# android how to remove the notification small icon from top left screen

Tags: android, icons, android-notifications

I have this code that build notification, i need to remove the small icon on top left screen, i need to ask if there any method that prevent displaying this icon when create a notification

```
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.mynotification);
    Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(
        getApplicationContext())
.setTicker(tickerText)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)// here how can i make it null or transparent
.setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(mContentIntent)

    .setVibrate(mVibratePattern)
    .setContent(notificationView);


    //the intent that is started when the notification is clicked (works)
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
            notificationIntent, 0);



    //this is the intent that is supposed to be called when the 
    //button is clicked
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, switchButtonListener.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
            switchIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeOnFlash, 
            pendingSwitchIntent);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appName, 
            pendingSwitchIntent);
    Notification not = notification.build();
    not.flags=Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    notificationManager.notify(1, not);
```

i need to leave the notification on status bar but WITHOUT displaying the small icon on top left

Comment: have you tried removing  setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

Comment: yes then the whole notification is removed !

Comment: I have answered it here, may be helpful for others thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795196/5923085

Answer (score -1):

okay now i found the solution:O just need to make this

```
.setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent)
```

Comment: This remove the icon of the notification bar When the push is received