# how to disable notification small icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, icons, android-notifications

How to `disable` or `hide` notification small icon ? I know it is mandatory but I want to hide or remove small icon and just show large icon.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(FcmIntentService.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_small_icon_transparent);
NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(11, builder.build());
```

i want something like this google plus notification:

[image]

Comment: .setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent)

Comment: Er. Arjun saini i have try this but show a red circle with white color inside it.

Comment: can u try also not set any setsmall icon or not use in code

Comment: small icon is mandatory if you don't set small icon notifications will not show

Answer (score 4):

You can hide this way.

```
.setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent)
```

Comment: It doesn't hide icon, but showing a gray empty circle (on Lollipop).

Answer (score 2):

Create custom notification and remove **.setStyle()** from notification builder.

Please read this doc before going through the code. very very helpful and will clear all of your doubts: [Android custom notification doc](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification)

Use the provided code and just make two layouts in your layout folder, one for collapsed view and another for expanded view( if u want to show expanded view)

```
// custom notification class
public class NotificationUtils {

private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();
private String channelId = "notification_channel";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE = 101;

private Context mContext;

public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
//Call this method in your FirebaseMessagingService class
public void showNotificationMessage(String billUrl, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0,intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
            );
    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelId);

        if (billUrl != null && billUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(billUrl).matches()) {
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(billUrl);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                showNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent);
            }
    }
}

private void showNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, String brandName,
                              String description, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent) {

    // Get the layouts to use in the custom notification
    RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.view_collapsed_notification);
    RemoteViews notificationLayoutExpanded = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.view_expanded_notification);


    //Null and Empty checks for your Key Value Pairs
    if (bitmap != null) {
        notificationLayoutExpanded.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.bill_container, bitmap);
    }

    if (brandName != null) {
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.content_title, brandName);
        notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.expand_content_title, brandName);
    }

    if (description != null) {
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.content_text, description);
        notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.expand_content_text, description);
    }

    if (timeStamp != null) {
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.timestamp, timeStamp);
        notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.expand_timestamp, timeStamp);
    }

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_logo)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, mBuilder.build());

}


 // Downloading push notification image before displaying it in the notification tray
private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score -3):

Just use only 
`.setLargeIcon(getBitmap(R.drawable.large_icon))` and for .`setSmallIcon()` use a transparent image.